# Analogue web3.eth.accounts.sign (from web3js) in web3py

Tags: web3js, web3.py

There is a function web3.eth.accounts.sign in the implementation of web3js. But I cannot find the exact equivalent in web3py I don't see this. I found something similar to this — the signHash function (link https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-message). This documentation says that the same hashing mechanism, but as a result, execution returns not the same as in web3js (web3.eth.accounts.sign).

I used this function in web3js to get signature (and then using ECDSA library (on Solidity) to get signer. On web3js works correctly (but on web3py - no). I connect to test network (ropsten) via Infura.

On web3js (where msg - what is signed):

```js
let signature = await web3.eth.accounts.sign(msgHash, '0x' + privateKeyUser);
console.log('signature ='+signature.signature);
```

On web3py (I try, but doesn't work):

```py
signature = web3.eth.account.signHash(msgHash, '0x' + privateKeyUser)
print('signature ='+signature.signature.hex())
```

And for example in variable "msgHash" value: 0x058c3b4c8e5dc4632b5c6b861b2c1861d53e426dc673c907ddf2651942b0f230
And at the output of web3js function (web3.eth.accounts.sign), we get signature:
0xd19241ed816026e846c8511e03a468aa6e038165ecb3c2229eee38b04c64b235408389dfad2b65d776dba236e7de1b63fdb6b2579e70c4ce9ad1b09a35da96521c
And this is the correct value. Web3py has other value.

What is exact analogue in web3py of how this web3.eth.accounts.sign function works in web3js?
Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an example message that you are trying to sign, as well as the raw (hex-encoded) data that `web3.js` produces.

Comment: It would also be good to know if you are using a remote node to sign / handle keys, or if the private key to sign with is available in-script to `web3.js`. (There is this distinction in `web3.py`.)

Comment: In general, convenience methods for EIP-712 structured signing were [added to `web3.py` in v5](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/pull/1319); the `stable` docs you link to are v4. Do clarify if you specifically need v4, or if v5 is also acceptable.

Comment: ...And since you're new to SE: these clarifications should go as edits to your original question. (Welcome! :D)

Comment: Thanks for help! Yes, I'm new here :) I added more information.

Comment: Help me please. I added more information in my initial question. I still don't know answer.

Comment: About this - "In general, convenience methods for EIP-712 structured signing were added to web3.py in v5; the stable docs you link to are v4. Do clarify if you specifically need v4, or if v5 is also acceptable."

Comment: (end of my previous post) I tried both version  - 4 and 5. Before this, I didn't try version 5 (because it is unstable, as I understand it). In version 5 I see opportunity to work with the "send_message" function. If I understand correctly, need pass instance of "SignableMessage" class (from eth_account.messages). But I don’t understand to the end what correct parameters for initialization of this instance.

Comment: @Alex Welcome to stack exchange! This question would be improved by adding a private key (obviously a "burner" key, since it will be made public), and the expected signature result, to make it fully reproducible. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @carver, I showed in initial description of this question pieces of code describing my problem. But also I can add that then I pass signature to smart contract and use ECDSA library on Solidity (from OpenZeppelin) - function ECDSA.recover for extract signer.

Comment: @carver I added in initial description expected result of the signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you mentioned in comments that you're open to using web3.py v5, here is the [v5 approach to sign a message](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-message):

```
from eth_account import Account, messages

msg_hash_hex = "058c3b4c8e5dc4632b5c6b861b2c1861d53e426dc673c907ddf2651942b0f230"
private_key_hex = "b25c7db31feed9122727bf0939dc769a96564b2de4c4726d035b36ecf1e5b364"

#// This part prepares "version E" messages, using the EIP-191 standard
message = messages.encode_defunct(hexstr=msg_hash_hex)

#// This part signs any EIP-191-valid message
signed_message = Account.sign_message(message, private_key=private_key_hex)
print("signature =", signed_message.signature.hex())
```

If you'd like to know more about EIP-191, check out the original [EIP-191 writeup](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-191). It's short and readable.

That snippet is equivalent to the javascript:

```
msgHash = "0x058c3b4c8e5dc4632b5c6b861b2c1861d53e426dc673c907ddf2651942b0f230"
privateKeyUser = "b25c7db31feed9122727bf0939dc769a96564b2de4c4726d035b36ecf1e5b364"

// web3.js sign() *only* supports "version E" EIP-191 signing
// so it adds the preamble for you.
let signature = await web3.eth.accounts.sign(msgHash, '0x' + privateKeyUser);
console.log('signature ='+signature.signature);
```

Note that the javascript [`sign()` method](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign) "signs arbitrary data" rather than a message hash. So although you appear to be hashing it first, you could sign the original message instead.

In the python version, prepare the original message for signing with: `encode_defunct(text=original_message)`.

Comment: Thank you for answer!
But I have not succeeded on your advice:

Comment: 1) In version with web3py,  I have error:
"AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'"
I converted "msg_hash" variable to text. Line with "encode_defunct" has become:
"message = encode_defunct(text="0x058c3b4c8e5dc4632b5c6b861b2c1861d53e426dc673c907ddf2651942b0f230")"

Comment: And after that it started without errors. and result is: 
0x4ef46c84d3b33927369c69da0aa46328a80c88f747ee33e9a597e76e8cf8a723642302bf793c1b80b8979a97416ff64423f0b4cad8a1f0e5e141b3f2a219b3881b

Comment: 2) In version with web3js, I don't have errors. And result:
0xdccea59712c525f67783bc2c6bb5add55447d3f2122f30eccb602c3e629a609f2a13c74c32fcb15799c94d3e00753c7264aee93339b327c2130e2f02ce4abb5c1b

As you can see, results are not same.

Comment: As you can see, results are not same.

For information:
I have version of web3py - 5.0.0b2, and version of web3js - 1.0.0-beta.55

Comment: Ah, sorry about about the typo in `encode_defunct`. I updated the answer, and I get the same result as you got with web3js.

Comment: Checked, now it works correctly! @carver, thank you very much!

Comment: @carver how to sign a hash I already have directly instead of the message ?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without seeing the content of all variables, including keys.

But my gut feeling is that you are mixing raw bytes and hexadecimal ASCII strings - some of the variables are not what you think they are.

If possible can you edit your question with a lot of prints and output to compare?

Comment: Thank you for answer!
I need to write a variable where is private key? I think this is only one thing that missing here. Data mixing - in my opinion, here I wrote them as strings explicitly).
Please correct me if I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone came here with `web3.py < v5`:

Use [defunct_hash_message](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/stable/eth_account.html#eth_account.messages.defunct_hash_message) on the message before using `signHash`.

```py
from eth_account.messages import defunct_hash_message
prepared_message = defunct_hash_message(primitive=msgHash)
signature = web3.eth.account.signHash(prepared_message, '0x' + privateKeyUser)
print('signature =' + signature.signature.hex())
```